# The necessary and sufficient constraint of $A$ such that $\text{tr}(A^n)\geq0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-analysis

I'm looking for a sufficient and necessary constraint for the complex square matrix $A$ such that $\text{tr}(A^n)\geq0$ for $n=1,2,3...$

Up to now, it seems that the eigenvalues of $A$ must come in  real numbers or complex conjugate pairs if we want $\text{tr}(A^n)\in\mathbb{R}$ for $n=1,2,3...$ (Whereas, I can't give a proof).

So, if we want $\text{tr}(A^n)\geq 0$ for $n=1,2,3...$, what further constraints do we need to impose on the eigenvalues of $A$?

Comment: If real eigenvalues  are positive then it is sufficient condition as eigenvalues of $A^n$ are powers of eigenvalues equal $\lambda ^n$ and trace is the sum of eigenvalues, If $n$ is even it is sufficient for them  to be real.

Comment: Have you tried using Jordan Normal Form?

Comment: @Widawensen Thanks for the comment,  I get your point, but maybe I am more interested in the necessary conditions of $A$.

Comment: @askingquestions Uhhh...I have no idea to use Jordan Normal Form to give proof or a construction...

Comment: Oh, I see. I would try reading the statement at least, since I'm quite sure it would make your life quite easier. :-) Essentially what it says is that given a complex matrix you can find a similar matrix that is in a very simple form (read the formal statement for detail). When you exponentiate the matrix in this form it will continue being in a not-horrible form, and it's simple enough that the traces can be easily found.

Comment: @askingquestions Yep! Utilizing Jordan Normal Form we can find that $\text{tr}(A^n)=\sum_{i}\lambda_i^n$, where $\lambda_i$ are eigenvalues of $A$. So maybe I should post this question in the sector of Real- or Complex-Analysis.

Comment: @Hezaraki I don't think it's the prettiest approach, but you could use [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_identities) to argue that if each $k$th-power-sum is non-negative, then the roots satisfy a polynomial with real coefficients, which means that they be real or come in conjugate pairs.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you very much, Ben.  In the [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4507057/what-is-the-necessary-condition-on-lambda-i-such-that-sum-i-lambda-i?noredirect=1&lq=1),  Conrad also mentioned  Newton's identities in the proof of the statement that "$\lambda_i$  appear as real numbers or conjugate pairs if  $\sum_{i}\lambda_i^n\in\mathbb{R}$".

Comment: @BenGrossmann BTW, do you have any insights or suggestions for further restrictions on the eigenvalues $\{\lambda_i\}$ by the stronger condition that "each $k$th-power-sum is non-negative"?  : )

Comment: @Hezaraki I do not

Comment: @BenGrossmann Anyway, thanks a lot!  : )