# What is the necessary condition on $\{\lambda_i\}$ such that $\sum_{i}\lambda_i^n\geq0$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

I'm looking for the necessary condition on the set $S$ consisting of $m$ complex numbers $\big(S=\{\lambda_i|i=1,2,...,m\}\subset\mathbb C\big)$ such that

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{m}\lambda_i^n\geq0
$$
for any $n\geq1$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

It seems that the necessary condition of $
\sum_{i=1}^{m}\lambda_i^n\in\mathbb{R}
$ is that the elements of $S$ must come in real numbers or complex conjugate pairs. (Whereas, I can't prove it)

(The question is closely related to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4507015/760030).)

Comment: If $\sum_{i=1}^{m}\lambda_i^n\in\mathbb{R}$ by conjugating we have $\sum_{i=1}^{m}\lambda_i^n= \sum_{i=1}^{m}\overline {\lambda_i^n}$ so eliminating the real ones and the conjugate pairs we get either that $S$ is as required (reals and conjugate pairs) or $\sum \alpha_k^n=\sum \beta_k^n$ for some distinct sets of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (at least one non void); but considering the monic polynomials $P,Q$ with roots the $\alpha$ and the $\beta$ respectively, Newton's identities show that they have same coefficients hence are equal so that is a contradiction

Comment: for non negativity it gets more complicated as one can have various examples like $\lambda_1=a >0, |\lambda_k|<a$ (small enough so non negativity holds for small $n$), but also $\lambda_1=a >0, \lambda_2=-a, \lambda_3=b >0, b<a$ and the rest as before, but also the full set of roots of unity of some fixed order $k$ works, so not sure exactly what you want unless you are more specific

Comment: Probably one can prove that at least one maximum modulus value must be positive (so by scaling and assuming $|\lambda_k|\le 1$ that $\lambda_1=1$)

Comment: @Conrad Many thanks for all the wonderful comments!  For the first comment:  I'm not familiar with Newton's identities (to be honest, never heard them before). So I think I need to take some time to understand your proof; For the second one:  Up to now, I don't have any more requirements for  $S$ than $\sum_{i}^{m}\lambda_i^n\geq0$.

Comment: @Conrad Oh, sorry for my slow-witted, I just got your meaning in your third comment. I think it may be a very nice starting point.

Comment: In this context Newton's identities show how to express the symmetric polynomials in $x_1,..x_k$ (coefficients of the monic polynomials with roots $x_1,..x_k$, so stuff like $x_1+..x_k, x_1x_2+ x_1x_3+...+x_{k-1}x_k, x_1..x_k$) in terms of the power sums of $x_1,..x_k$ and viceversa; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities   will think how to prove the necessity of the claim above when the sum is non negative, but shouldn't be too hard

Comment: @Conrad I see. Again, my sincere thanks for your generosity and patience.